# Vector of pairs invalid vector<T> subscript

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having a problem with the code below. My compiler tells me that I have an

```
 _Xout_of_range("invalid vector<T> subscript");
```

And I've been running through all of my code to try and find out where it is located. My professor said that it has something to do with me using .size() or when I try to find the size of my vector I'm doing something extra causing it to go out of bounds. Is there any advice you guys can recommend?

```
//
//DiscreteDistribution.hpp
//

#ifndef _DISCRETE_DISTRIBUTION_GUARD
#define _DISCRETE_DISTRIBUTION_GUARD

#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "Random.h"
#include "Types.h"

//Reference used: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

/*
// Map-based distribution <KEY, WEIGHT>
//     where the weight is cumulative (allowing random number generation)
//     to return the key value
*/
template<typename KEY_T>
class DiscreteDistribution
{
private:

    WEIGHT_T max() const
    {
        return _valueToWeightMap.back().second;
    }

public:
    DiscreteDistribution() :_valueToWeightMap{}, _rng{}
    {}

    DiscreteDistribution(const DiscreteDistribution<KEY_T>& orig) : _valueToWeightMap {orig._valueToWeightMap}
    {

    }

    const DiscreteDistribution& operator=(const DiscreteDistribution<KEY_T>& orig)
    {
        return orig;
    }

    virtual ~DiscreteDistribution()
    {
        _valueToWeightMap.clear();
    }

    /* @param key -- key value for mapping
    * @param weight -- weight of the particular key
    *    If the key is not in the distribution, add it, otherwise,
    * @throws std::string object for negative weights (when the @param weight is cast to a standard int)
    */

    void add(KEY_T key, WEIGHT_T weights)
    {
        WEIGHT_T delta = 0;

        bool keycheck = false;

        int index = -1;

        //Throw exception if weight below zero.
        if ( (int) weights < 0)
        {
            throw std::string("Warning::was this weight intended; Negative weight?");
        }

        //Check for existing pairs.
        for (int i = 0; i < _valueToWeightMap.size(); i++)
        {
            //If _vTwM index equals key. Set the index to 'i' and boolean to true.
            if (_valueToWeightMap.at(i).first == key)
            {
                index = i;
                keycheck = true;
            }
        }

        //If the index is less than zero...and there are no existing pairs.
        if (index < 0)
        {
            //And keycheck is true (see past evaluation above)...
            if (keycheck)   
            {
                //Get the max weight and set it to instance variable WEIGHT_T delta and add it to the 'weights' value
                //to get the new weight to add to the pair.
                delta = _valueToWeightMap.at(_valueToWeightMap.size()).second;
                weights += delta;
            }

            //New pair to push back.
            _valueToWeightMap.push_back(std::pair<KEY_T, WEIGHT_T> ( key, weights ));

        }
        else 
        {
            //Find the change in weight set to delta.
            delta = _valueToWeightMap.at(index).second - ((int) weights);

            //Loop through and find the change in weight at each 'i'.
            for (int i = index; i < _valueToWeightMap.size(); i++)
            {
                _valueToWeightMap.at(i).second -= delta;
            }
        }
    }

    /* @param key -- key value for mapping
    * @return the weight in the discrete distribution
    * Get the weight at the given key value.
    */

    WEIGHT_T weight(KEY_T key) const
    {   
        WEIGHT_T weightAtKey;

        for (int i = 0; i < _valueToWeightMap.size(); i++)
        {
            //if the key _value at the index i is equal to the key value being passed in...get it's weight (if it has one).
            if (_valueToWeightMap.at(i).first == key)
            {
                //Current minus the prev to get the weight difference.
                weightAtKey = _valueToWeightMap.at(i).second - _valueToWeightMap.at(i - 1).second;  
            }
        }
        return weightAtKey;
    }

    /*
    * Take the value(key) at whatever the index and divide that over the cumulative weight to find the
    * probability after adjusting for the difference.
    */
    double DiscreteDistribution::probability(KEY_T key) const
    {
        //Set the weight by finding the given key value's weight.
        double wgt = (double) weight(key);

        if (wgt != 0)
        {
            //Take the cumulative weight divided by the max to get probability.
            return  wgt / max();

        }
        return 0;
    }

    // @return Based on the given weights, roll a die to return the resulting key value
    // Use Random rng to find this.
    KEY_T operator()() const
    {
        //Find the cumulative weight between 1 and the max.
        int die = _rng.nextInt(1, max());

        //Loop through and compare weights and return the key that closely corresponds to the weight found.
        //Example <'A', 49>
        //        <'B', 40>
        //        <'C', 35>
        //Die roll is 45. Since 45 is less than the key value at 'A', it will not return' A', but instead,
        //Returns 'B' since it's the closest value to 45.

        for(std::pair<KEY_T, WEIGHT_T> pair : _valueToWeightMap)
        {
            if(die <= pair.second)
            {
                return pair.first;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }


    // toString and overloaded output operator
    std::string toString() const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DiscreteDistribution& dis)
    {
        //Simply output the ToString.
        os << dis.toString();
        return os;
    }

protected:

    // Map of keys to cumulative weights
    std::vector<std::pair<KEY_T, WEIGHT_T> > _valueToWeightMap;

    // The random number generator
    Random _rng;

};

#endif
```

Comment: Now is an excellent time to learn how to use your debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Your professor is right. You cannot index a vector at its `size()` because containers are 0-indexed in C++.

This goes out of bounds:

```
_valueToWeightMap.at(_valueToWeightMap.size())
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access vector at size. The culprit is this line

```
delta = _valueToWeightMap.at(_valueToWeightMap.size()).second;
```

If you want to access the last element just do this

```
delta = _valueToWeightMap.at(_valueToWeightMap.size() - 1).second;
```

**EDIT**
More elegant way will be calling .back() as following -

```
delta = _valueToWeightMap.back().second;
```

Comment: Unless the vector is empty of course! And if it's not, [`.back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) will do the same thing.

Comment: Actually I have no idea about this. Haven't tried it. I'll give it a try for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have one more `put of bounds` error in your `weight` function at line

`weightAtKey = _valueToWeightMap.at(i).second - _valueToWeightMap.at(i - 1).second;`

While you iterating through your vector with index 0, you can try to substract an item with index -1.